# Bootstrap DropDownMenu does not work when Iframe-Wrapper is loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, joomla

I have a Joomla site that uses the Twitter Bootstrap Hover Dropdown Plugin in its template.

I added some pages to this Joomla project with PHP and Javascript (JQuery). That pages are linked with an Iframe-Wrapper.

After opening a Joomla menu link that shows such an external page, the Bootstrap dropdown-menu looses its functionality.

Now I found out, that the disfunction of the Bootstrap Dropdown Menu is directly caused by the Iframe-Wrapper of Joomla whether I use JQuery or not inside the wrapper.

I loaded a simple page into the Iframe-Wrapper. This page does not load JQuery and does not use any JavaScript. The result is the same:

After loading the Iframe-Wrapper the Bootstrap Dropdown Menu stops to work.

After click on another menu item (that is not linked to an Iframe-Wrapper) the DropDown resumes working normal.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I added the following command to the **index.php** of my Joomla **template.**

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

Now JQuery (needed by bootstrap) works in Joomla also after loading an iframe-wrapper page.

I found the solution in this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580724/joomla-menu-item-type-iframe-wrapper-doesnt-load-javascript):

Answer (score 0):

**Do not load the Jquery twice**. Load it only once, that is *either* with **Twitter Bootstrap Hover Dropdown** *or* with **Iframe-Wrapper**

Comment: Ok, I could remove the command to load JQuery from my PHP project. But of course JQuery should only not load, if it is already loaded.  How can this be done? How can I check if JQuery is already loaded?

Comment: Check the source code of your site on the browser. You can get there whether it is included or not.